# Gradient not working when there's a background color

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

so I'm trying to add a gradient text to my website, however, it doesn't work when there's a background color.

```css
#maintitle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
* {
    background-color: #1c232d;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="title" id="maintitle">
  <h1>
    Welcome!
  </h1>
</div>
```

What is causing it?How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to add gradient to text  color or gradient background?

Comment: @Tushar Gradient text

Comment: @joelzinae: it seems to work in the code you've posted; I've converted that code into a runnable snippet. Please could you edit it to show the "non-working" behaviour you describe? The obvious solution to your problem would seem to be that the `background-color` is clipped - as is the background-gradient - to the text.

Comment: There isn't a background colour in the code you've posted. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that *demonstrates the problem*.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, I've added the snipped for the background color.

Comment: You've set a background on the h1 so of course it will cover up the background on the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a gradient as a background-image *and*  a background-color for the same element, only one of them will be displayed if they both cover the complete element (which they do as long as no clipping is added, and if it's added, both are clipped).

For an additional background color you need to add an additional parent element that gets that background color:

(note after edit of question snippet: also the `*` selector applies to the `#maintitle` element in your snippet, so although there are two CSS rules, the `background-image` and `background-color` settings in them apply to the same element, for which the above also applies: the background-color overwrites the background-imge/gradient)

```css
#maintitle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title" id="maintitle">
    <h1>
      Welcome!
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```